# How to write a Ruby (Minitest) unit test that fails if I don't have the correct require statements?

Tags: ruby, minitest

I have this test:

```
require 'minitest/autorun'                                                                                                                                                        
require 'minitest/color'                                                                                                                                                          
                                                                                                                                                                                  
require_relative '../lib/util/input_file'                                                                                                                                         
                                                                                                                                                                                  
class TestInputFile < Minitest::Test                                                                                                                                              
  def setup                                                                                                                                                                       
    @input_path = Pathname.new("/path/to/inputs")                                                                                                         
  end                                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                  
  def test_default_input_file                                                                                                                                                     
    input_file = Util::InputFile.new(1)                                                                                                                                       
    expected_path = @input_path.join('input01.txt')                                                                                                                               
    assert_equal(expected_path, input_file.abspath)                                                                                                                               
  end

  # more tests follow                                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

for this code:

```
module Util                                                                                                                                                                       
  class InputFile                                                                                                                                                                 
    def initialize(num)                                                                                                                                                     
      @num = num
      @input_dir = Pathname.new("/path/to/inputs")                                                                                                                                                         
    end                                                                                                                                                             
                                                                                                                                                                                  
    def abspath                                                                                                                                                                   
      basename = 'input'                                                                                                                                     
      return @input_dir.join(format('%s%02d.txt', basename, @num))                                                                                                                
    end                                                                                                                                                                           
  end                                                                                                                                                                             
end
```

When I run this with `rake test`, everything passes as expected; however, when I call it from my actual main script, it chokes with `uninitialized constant Util::InputFile::Pathname (NameError)`.  When I add `require 'pathname'` at the top of `lib/util/input_file.rb`, everything is fine.

Why does the unit test not fail in the same way, and how can I refactor it such that it will fail unless I have the correct require statement in the production code?

**EDIT:** Rakefile is as follows:

```
require 'minitest/test_task'

Minitest::TestTask.create do |t|
  t.test_globs = ['test/**/test*.rb']
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To run tests separately use `rake test:isolated` instead of `rake test`.

https://github.com/minitest/minitest#rake-tasks-

It seems like one of your other tests gets `Pathname` loaded.

Answer (score 0):

How does your Rakefile look and doesn't it get `pathname` required? It can explain why your test (started with `rake test`) goes well.

And why don't you want to require `pathname` at the top of lib/util/input_file.rb?

Comment: see the edit for the Rakefile. Also, to be clear, I absolutely do want to require pathname in input_file.rb. Because I want that, I want the unit tests to fail if that's not true so I can catch it and fix it more quickly, so I'm trying to understand how to adjust my unit test setup so they will fail when I don't have the require statement.